# My SQL query getting info from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to make a new widget for my gallery where it can show me the last updated albums. The last uploaded images have always the higher pid, and the pictures can only be in one album.

But after long time trying to do something I did something, but I got two problems:
First: there's no album title.
Second: It doesn't show me the thumb that I've selected.

Here is my code

```
<?php
    require_once('include/config.inc.php');
    header("Content-type: application/x-javascript");

    $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass') or die('Error conexion server');
    $connect_db = mysql_select_db('database', $connect) or die ('Error conexion base de datos');

                $resultado = mysql_query(" SELECT DISTINCT(aid) FROM cpgq7_pictures ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 0 ,6", $connect) or die('Ningun album encontrado');

                echo 'document.write(\'';

                    if(mysql_num_rows($resultado) == 0){
                        echo 'Ningun album obtenido';
                    } else {

echo '<div class="photos">  ';
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
                            echo ' ';
                                $album_id = $row['aid'];
                                $subresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cpgq7_pictures where aid=$album_id order by pid DESC LIMIT 0, 6");
                                $album_title = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cpgq7_albums where aid=$album_id DESC LIMIT 0, 6");

                                if(mysql_num_rows($subresult) == 0){
                                    $album_img = "http://link/thumbs/thumb_nopic.png";
                                } else {
                                    while($subrow = mysql_fetch_array($subresult)){
                                        $album_img = "http://link/albums/".$subrow['filepath'].'normal_'.$subrow['filename']  .$subrow['datebrowse'];
                                    }
                                }
                                echo '<div class="g-album">';
                                    echo '<a href="http://link/thumbnails.php?album='.$album_id.' " target="_blank"><img src="'.$album_img.'" alt="" /></a>';
                                    echo '<div class="g-title"><a href="http://link/thumbnails.php?album='.$album_id.' " target="_blank">'.$album_title.'</a></div>';
                                echo "</div>";
                        }
                        echo '</div>';
                    }
                    echo '\');';
            ?>
```

In cpgp7_pictures you will find: "pid", "aid", "filepath", "filename", etc.
And in cpgp7_albums you will find: "aid", "title", "thumb" (the pid of the cover)

Example:

```
cpgp7_pictures

pid       aid    filepath          filename
21074     159    userpics/10002/   CREATIONS00004.jpg
21073     405    userpics/10002/   LMH00003.jpg
21072     405    userpics/10002/   LMH00002.jpg
21071     405    userpics/10002/   LMH00001.jpg

cpgp7_albums

aid       title                                    thumb
405       T-Mobile, Las Vegas - CreationsOfLa      21074
159       Love Me Harder - Jones Crow              21071
```

And the loaded widget should be something like:

```
<div class="photos">
    <div class="g-album">
    <a href="http://arianagrandechile.net/galeria/thumbnails.php?album=405" target="_blank"><img src="http://arianagrandechile.net/galeria/albums/userpics/10002/normal_CREATIONS00004.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <div class="g-title"><a href="http://arianagrandechile.net/galeria/thumbnails.php?album=405" target="_blank">T-Mobile, Las Vegas - CreationsOfLa</a></div>
</div>
```

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Please don't use archaic, insecure and deprecated code.

Comment: Don't use mysql functions, use mysqli or PDO functions instead and prepared queries. That said, you could easily combine all of your queries into a single query, then just step through, creating divs as needed.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that the code mimics sql joins within php code.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT(aid)`note that SQL's `DISTINCT` keyword is not a function..

Comment: I don't know what else I can use, Im a newbie in mysql, and the database can't be modified because coppermine works like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing your joins in PHP, use a single SQL query to get the data.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `cpgq7_pictures` a
JOIN `cpgq7_albums` b
    ON a.`aid` = b.`aid`
GROUP BY a.`aid`, a.`pid`
ORDER BY a.`aid`, a.`pid` DESC 
LIMIT 0, 6
```

You won't need to limit the rows from cpgq7_albums since each picture should only match one album.

**EDIT** *Created a SQLFiddle to show the query*

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc24e1/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cpgp7_pictures` (
    `pid`       INT(11) UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT  COMMENT 'Primary Key',
    `aid`       INT(11) UNSIGNED        NULL        DEFAULT NULL,
    `filepath`  VARCHAR(200)            NOT NULL    DEFAULT '',
    `filename`  VARCHAR(200)            NOT NULL    DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`pid`)
) 
    ENGINE=MyISAM 
    AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
    COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
    COMMENT '';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cpgp7_albums` (
    `aid`       INT(11) UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT  COMMENT 'Primary Key',
    `title`     VARCHAR(200)            NOT NULL    DEFAULT '',
    `thumb`     INT(11) UNSIGNED        NULL        DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`aid`)
) 
    ENGINE=MyISAM 
    AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
    COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
    COMMENT '';



INSERT INTO `cpgp7_pictures`
(`pid`,`aid`,`filepath`,`filename`)
VALUES
(21074,159,'userpics/10002/','CREATIONS00004.jpg'),
(21073,405,'userpics/10002/','LMH00003.jpg'),
(21072,405,'userpics/10002/','LMH00002.jpg'),
(21071,405,'userpics/10002/','LMH00001.jpg');

INSERT INTO `cpgp7_albums`
(`aid`,`title`,`thumb`)
VALUES
(405,'T-Mobile, Las Vegas - CreationsOfLa',21074),
(159,'Love Me Harder - Jones Crow',21071)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `cpgp7_pictures` a
JOIN `cpgp7_albums` b
    ON a.`aid` = b.`aid`
GROUP BY a.`aid`, a.`pid`
ORDER BY a.`aid`, a.`pid` DESC 
LIMIT 0, 6
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc24e1/2/0)**:

```
|   pid | aid |        filepath |           filename | aid |                               title | thumb |
|-------|-----|-----------------|--------------------|-----|-------------------------------------|-------|
| 21074 | 159 | userpics/10002/ | CREATIONS00004.jpg | 159 |         Love Me Harder - Jones Crow | 21071 |
| 21073 | 405 | userpics/10002/ |       LMH00003.jpg | 405 | T-Mobile, Las Vegas - CreationsOfLa | 21074 |
| 21072 | 405 | userpics/10002/ |       LMH00002.jpg | 405 | T-Mobile, Las Vegas - CreationsOfLa | 21074 |
| 21071 | 405 | userpics/10002/ |       LMH00001.jpg | 405 | T-Mobile, Las Vegas - CreationsOfLa | 21074 |
```

**2nd EDIT**

*PHP Code to run query and output divs.*

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);
    if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>Error connecting to db: ".$mysqli->connect_errno.", ".$mysqli->connect_error."</p>\n";
    } else {
        $qstr = "";
        $qstr .= "SELECT\n";
        $qstr .= "  a.`aid`,\n";
        $qstr .= "  a.`pid`,\n";
        $qstr .= "  a.`filepath`,\n";
        $qstr .= "  a.`filename`,\n";
        $qstr .= "  b.`title`,\n";
        $qstr .= "  b.`thumb`\n";
        $qstr .= "FROM `cpgp7_pictures` a\n";
        $qstr .= "JOIN `cpgp7_albums` b\n";
        $qstr .= "    ON a.`aid` = b.`aid`\n";
        $qstr .= "GROUP BY a.`aid`\n";
        $qstr .= "ORDER BY a.`aid`\n";
        $qstr .= "LIMIT 0, 6;";
        $results = $mysqli->query($qstr);
        if($results) {
            while($row = $results=>fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<div class='photos'>\n";
                echo "    <div class='g-album'>\n";
                echo "    <a href='http://arianagrandechile.net/galeria/thumbnails.php?album=".$row['aid']."' target='_blank'><img src='http://arianagrandechile.net/galeria/albums/".$row['filepath']."normal_".$row['filename']."' alt='' /></a>\n";
                echo "    <div class='g-title'><a href='http://arianagrandechile.net/galeria/thumbnails.php?album=$row['aid']' target='_blank'>".$row['title']."</a></div>\n";
                echo "</div>\n";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This won't work reliable because it's not a ANSI SQL query concerning the GROUP BY.. Besides functional dependency is also out of the equation

Comment: Edit your question and add example data for the two tables. Then I could create a SQL fiddle to test the query.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, it is MySQL specific regarding the group by and not ANSI SQL, but the OP tagged the question as MySQL. Not sure what you mean by `functional dependency' though.

Comment: @SloanThrasher is it easier if I upload the database?

Comment: Nope. Just enough data from the two tables to create a simple test, and their create table statements. Or better yet, create a SQL Fiddle and add the link to your question.

Comment: @SloanThrasher there you have an example

Comment: Table create statements?

Comment: @SloanThrasher em I don't know what you are trying to tell me.. but the database can't be modified because Coppermine works in that way.

Comment: Not asking you to modify the tables/db. Just edit your question and add the table create statements for the two tables so I can create a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: "it is MySQL specific regarding the group by and not ANSI SQL" on MySQL this query could generate the wrong results for the select columns not used in the GROUP BY that is what i mean..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, thanks for the explanation. Of course you are right.

Comment: @SloanThrasher sadly Im not an expert and I don't know which information I have to gave to you.

Comment: Not a problem, I guessed at the table schemas to create the SQL Fiddle. See my updated answer

Comment: @SloanThrasher thank you but the results should only display one aid I mean only one result with the same aid

Comment: So you want only one picture per `aid`? Just change the group by to just the aid and not the pid

Comment: Here's an updated [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc24e1/3/0) that does that.

Comment: @SloanThrasher thank you so much, and now how do I call them in my echo ''; ?

Comment: See added PHP code. This should give you an idea how the output can be formatted. If you need further help, you'll need to play with code yourself to fine tune it. If my answer basically solves your problem, please accept it.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Thank you so so much for your help! You're the best

Comment: @SloanThrasher can you please send me an email? vbamauricio@gmail.com I have a question its simple but I need your help